# Slicing non consecutive dates in timeseries in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, slice

I want to slice out non-consecutive dates in a Pandas timeseries.  I can extract a single date and I can do the same for consecutive dates but when I try to extract non consecutive dates I fail.  I give below for reproducibility purposes a toy data set and my code.

```
toy_data.to_json()
'{"MMM":{"1459382400000":7335000000.0,"1467244800000":7493333333.3333330154,"1475193600000":7677666666.6666669846,"1483142400000":7582333333.3333330154,"1490918400000":7447666666.6666669846,"1498780800000":7726666666.6666669846,"1506729600000":7930666666.6666669846,"1514678400000":8111333333.3333330154,"1522454400000":7990000000.0,"1530316800000":7990000000.0},"AOS":{"1459382400000":638566666.6666666269,"1467244800000":646933333.3333333731,"1475193600000":672633333.3333333731,"1483142400000":688633333.3333333731,"1490918400000":712066666.6666666269,"1498780800000":739400000.0,"1506729600000":742100000.0,"1514678400000":756133333.3333333731,"1522454400000":768600000.0,"1530316800000":768600000.0}}'

toy_data.loc['2018-06-30']
Company
MMM    7.990000e+09
AOS    7.686000e+08
Name: 2018-06-30 00:00:00, dtype: float64

toy_data.loc[['2018-06-30', '2017-06-30']]
KeyError: "None of [['2018-06-30', '2017-06-30']] are in the [index]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `index` is datetime format it  will failed , try convert to str

```
df.index=df.index.astype(str)
df.loc[['2018-06-30', '2017-06-30']]
Out[193]: 
                    AOS           MMM
2018-06-30  768600000.0  7.990000e+09
2017-06-30  739400000.0  7.726667e+09
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to query your dataframe using locators of type `str`. Notice that your index is of dtype `datetime64`:

```
toy_data.index.dtype
```

Yields:

```
datetime64[ns]
```

You need to recast as `str`:

```
toy_data.index = toy_data.index.astype(str)
```

Then you can query using type `str`:

```
toy_data.loc[['2017-06-30', '2018-06-30']]
```

Which gives:

```
                     MMM          AOS
2017-06-30  7.726667e+09  739400000.0
2018-06-30  7.990000e+09  768600000.0
```